# Multiple calculations over spark dataframe in one pass

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to make such several computations over data frame: min and max over column A, distinct values over column B. What is the most efficient way to do that? Is it possible to do that in one pass?

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "John"),
  (2, "John"),
  (3, "Dave"),
)).toDF("A", "B")
```

Comment: What do you mean by one pass?

Comment: I think my question could be not valid cause of lack of understanding of underlaying mechanism of aggregation computation in the distributed environment. I tried to compare the computation as if it is done over an array, iterating over it only once (one pass).

Comment: Or if aggregation operation is done separately for each column than we have 2 passes: for each of 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

If by one pass you mean inside a single statement , you can do this as below -

```
sparkDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "John"),
  (2, "John"),
  (3, "Dave"),
)).toDF("A", "B")

sparkDF.select([F.max(F.col('A')),F.min(F.col('A')),F.countDistinct(F.col('B'))
```

Additionally you can provide sample data and the expected output you are looking for to better gauge the question